# Burninate [hide]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I draw your attention to the tag [hide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hide).

It's currently applied to 10 questions, all of which have something to do with hiding, or not hiding, something. (At least none of them are about animal skin.)

- Unhiding comments in YouTube
- Hiding comments in Dropbox file viewer
- Hide off-hours in Google Calendar
- Hide from friends-of-a-friend on Facebook (x2)
- Hide from someone on Facebook
- Hide non-local jobs on LinkedIn
- Hide Twitter updates on LinkedIn
- Hide "liked" TV shows on Facebook
- Unhide a Facebook friend

Of course, there's no description or usage guidance.

The tag can't stand on its own on the question. There are no "experts" about hiding (except, maybe, Ninjas). It doesn't add any extra context.

I think this is a tag that we should eliminate.

Comment: Since this simply has upvotes and no comments, I'll take that as concurrence. I'll see about eliminating this tag within the next day or so. (Don't want to flood the front page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All uses of [hide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hide) have been removed.